# Cómo insertar un salto de línea?

Tags: c#, salto-de-linea

Buen día, alguien me podría ayudar con este caso por favor.

Necesito agregar un salto de línea para que no me muestre todo el texto señalado junto, sino organizado de forma vertical. Si alguien me puede ayudar con esto se lo agradecería.

**Adjunto el código:**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(textBox1.Text.ToString());
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ByO6Mod.cKpcRQj5_E5BI4IxxEKVwrxmpBLooY90m");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", "", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            IList<Parameter> Headers = response.Headers;
            var limit = response.Headers[1].Value;
            LblLimit.Text = limit.ToString();
            var remaining = response.Headers[2].Value;
            LblRemaining.Text = remaining.ToString();
            var reset = response.Headers[3].Value;
            LblReset.Text = reset.ToString();
            lblRespuesta.Text =response.Content+Environment.NewLine;
       }
```

Acá logré insertar un salto de línea pero no sé cómo agregarle más:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le agregué esto:

```
 lblRespuesta.Text = response.Content + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! generas un salto de linea, como estas haciendo, con Environment.NewLine... entonces cual seria la pregunta?

Comment: Me parece que lo mas recomendable sería llenar un objeto con esos datos en lugar de mostrarlos en json

Comment: Es una app de escritorio o web?

Comment: Es de escritorio

Answer (score 1):

Algunos protips:

- Separa las lineas dentro de tu funcione de manera semántica si es posible
- En general tu función realiza varias tareas, es buena práctica "destilar" funciones para que hagan una sola cosa correctamente. ej: una función para "atrapar" el evento y actuar respectivamente, y otra para imprimir los resultados en la pagina. O si estas debuggeando, usar las herramientas correspondientes
- Intenta no actuar sobre objector fuera del "scope", aunque esto depende de la situación, notarás que hace tu código más legible.
- Usa `string.format()` siempre que quieras formatear cualquier tipo de texto.

Sea como sea, sobre cómo agregar una línea, tienes algunas opciones:

1. Dar formato al texto. ej: usa `string.Format("hola mundo{}", Environment.NewLine)`
2. Darle formato a `lblRespuesta` para que haga el "breakline" del contenido, ej: `word-break:break-all;` si puede usar CSS, o similar. (no haz dado suficiente contexto en tu pregunta para saber).
3. Formatear el texto como json, puedes usar la libreria de c# `system.text.json` o alguna de las muchas en línea. Esta opción probablemente es la mejor si vas a recibir e imprimir mucho texto en formato json.

Suerte!

Comment: Css seria muy dificil... es una app de escritorio (se nota por la nomenclatura de variables y como le pasa datos a los controles) Te recomendaria leer [answer]... Gracias por la respuesta!!!!

Comment: Sí, es posible, aunque prefiero no asumir basado en nomeclatura. Lo habría reconsiderado si OP hubiese dado más contexto.

Comment: Esta perfecto!!! cuando tengas mas reputacion, vas a poder comentar y pedir aclaraciones para no tener que asumir nada...

Comment: Voy a darle upvote a la respuesta porque, aunque estoy de acuerdo con gbianchi, son consejos útiles y OP no nos da mucha información para responder con propiedad.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una respuesta en c# que, en apariencia, es una librería propia del núcleo .net:

Según la fuente, https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/mar/31/prettifying-a-json-string-in-net, todo lo que necesitas hacer se puede en una sola línea de código:

```
// Puedes utilizar esta línea de código en lugar de la que tienes al final
lblRespuesta.Text = JValue.Parse(response.Content).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```

Y con eso ya tendrías tu String formateado. Revisa en la fuente que librería debes importar para poder utilizar esa función.

¡Espero te funcione!

Comment: Me aparecen dos errores.

1. Error CS0103 El nombre 'Formatting' no existe en el contexto actual.
2. Error CS0103 El nombre 'JValue' no existe en el contexto actual.

Comment: @Banano A lo que he investigado, debe crearse una instancia de JValue en el método principal y simplementa llamarla en el "button1_click", por eso el error "CS0103 El nombre 'JValue' no existe en el contexto actual". El problema es que veo que el constructor de JValue siempre recibe un parametro, entonces eso me confunde un poco. Podrías intentar crearlo en el método principal y usarlo en el "button1_click" a ver si se logra algo así.